# Unix with few packages

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-terminal

I want a clean unix OS, just with two packages: `gnome-session-fallback` & usual ubuntu terminal. I want to minimize the space of my OS take. How can I create this custom OS & install them through usb stick to a few of HDD?

Answer (score 4):

You won't have a working system with just `gnome-session-fallback` and "usual ubuntu terminal" (whatever that is). For one, `gnome-session-fallback` has lots and lots of other packages as required direct and indirect dependencies.

If you want to install the absolute strict minimum to get a working `gnome-session-fallback`, you can use two approaches:

- Use the regular Ubuntu installer to install the OS, then, after installation, use `aptitude` or another tool to go through the installed packages (there should be a couple hundred of them) and uninstall everything you think you don't need. If it complains that it's an essential package or is required by something else then don't uninstall it. Still, you need to be very careful about some of the things you uninstall, you can easily break the system if you don't know what you're doing.
- Use a live distro or rescue system or other means to boot, and use `debootstrap` to install your system. `debootstrap` will truly install only the absolute minimum, much less than the Ubuntu installer does. But it's an expert method: you have to make sure to install a bootloader and kernel by yourself and configure a few files (like `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/fstab`) manually because `debootstrap` doesn't do that for you.

Once you've done this, use `apt-get --no-install-recommends install` to install `gnome-session-fallback` and "usual ubuntu terminal" (whatever that is). This will pull in only the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

By "create" I think you mean "install". Since your post is tagged Ubuntu what you want is a minimal install ISO [that you can download from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). Note that even a minimal distro will contain quite a bit more than two packages.

If you really want to build your own Linux (not recommended for beginners) you can try the [Linux From Scratch project](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that a `gnome-session-fallback` and usual Ubuntu terminal which is in really a `gnome-terminal` will not make you a running system.

A system needs much more to be alive, It needs a kernel, drivers, I/O modules , Window Manager , File Manager , etc....

So you have many choices to make a minimal Ubuntu running system. One of them as answered before is the `Ubuntu Minimal CD` but this is needs some expert in packages since the user will choose what software to download and install by the time of installing the Ubuntu Minimal, so you may make your system bigger than you need if you choose wrong packages. Plus, this needs an Internet Connection and it will download all packages directly from the Internet and not from the ISO.

So, as another choice, there is a project called [Ubuntu Mini Remix](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/) which contains  only the minimal set of software to make the system work.

You can download your flavor from [here](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to distrowatch.com and look for a small distro. An example small linux is puppy linux at

http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=puppy .

They have a search when you can look for "Old Computers" which is there best synonym to small.

http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=Old+Computers&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active